# NextJS + AWS Fargate: How to get Domain host name from Request Object

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-fargate

I have a docker container running an NextJs App on AWS Fargate.
This app is behind an AWS ELB and is connected to an AWS Route53 Zone - `abc.domain.com`
The app is running smoothly with no failures.

However, when I hit an API,
`request.header.get('host')` returns `localhost` instead of `abc.domain.com`

Is there a way I can retrieve `abc.domain.com` from the request object or headers ?

Is there a setting I need to turn on for this on the AWS side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Load balancer`, you can edit `Attributes`. `Preserve host header` can be enabled.

Comment: This is enabled. Yet the host is still localhost